# Cargar un Json en c# a un DataGridView

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, datagridview, webapi

tengo una web api que me retorna un JSON, el caso es que deseo insertar los datos que recibo en un DataGridView, Pero no me retorna ningún valor cuando compilo el código, gracias de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar con la consulta, C#

```
private void cargador()
        {


            string url = "http://api-rest-pro3.test/api/cliente";
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
            dynamic m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            foreach (var i in m)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i.id_clientes, i.Nom_cli, i.Correo, i.Telefono);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falta decirle a que tipo de objeto lo quieres deserealizar, ejemplo:
Esta clase deberias cambiarla por la que recibes en el json.

```
public class MiClase
{
  public string Nombre {get;set;}
  public string Apellido {get;set;}
}
```

Luego en tu codigo llamas a la clase y si quieres rellenar un grid, seguramente deberia ser un list o array que estas recibiendo.

```
    private void cargador()
    {
        string url = "http://api-rest-pro3.test/api/cliente";

        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

        var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MiClase>>(json);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = m;
    }
```